# Dapper with Postgresql. Create JSONB TypeHandler

Tags: postgresql, mapping, dapper

Hers is my custom type handler for JSONB type in Postgresql

```cs
public class JsonTypeHandler : SqlMapper.ITypeHandler
{
    public void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, object value)
    {
        parameter.Value = (value == null)
            ? (object)DBNull.Value
            : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        parameter.DbType = DbType.String;
    }

    public object Parse(Type destinationType, object value)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value.ToString(), destinationType);
    }
}
```

I use it for map for example `IEnumerable<string>` property to Postgresql datatype. Here is my code

```cs
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(typeof(IEnumerable<string>), new JsonTypeHandler());
```

Parse method works find, but SetValue rises an Exception

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42804: field "FieldName" has type jsonb, but expression - text
```

This is because jsonb type has its own NpgsqlDbType.Json constant. Not DbType.String. How can I use custom type handler to map property to JSON data type?